# Xml layout for diagonal child layouts

Tags: android, xml

I am working on a photo collage app in which i have used custom view for rotating the image and zooming. But I am stuck at one thing. I have implemented below type of layouts successfully. 
[image]

But I am not getting an idea for making below type of collage.
[image]

please help me ASAP.

Comment: we can't find image there

Comment: for everyone, images are transparent, there is white colored content

Comment: posted the images. @Maneti Vinay

Comment: what do the images mean? are the triangles images or child views or what?

Comment: These are the collage images. Inside this image, the white background represents the custom views in which we can select image and rotate the images.@pskink

Answer (score 0):

One thing I could think of, if I were you, I'd look first at some rotation animations, at 45°, may be you should start from that, because that's not an easy layout, sorry if I'm mistaking

Comment: i already tried that. After doing that the custom view inside the child layout is rotating but whole layout is not rotating.